# Find first record based on start of string or until string is empty

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string lets say its something like this

```
var number = "02000123456";
```

And I have a list of records that hold a designation/number. My mind has gone blank in trying to figure this out, but I want to find the first record that match the first five digits and if none, then the first four digits and if none, three digits and so on.

I tried initially splitting the first 5 digits into an array and then doing a query using the array as a look up, but then its returning all of the matches.

<strike>I was hoping this is doable without using loops. And just using Linq.</strike>

Is it possible to write this in a single line or couple of lines without the need to write a foreach/for loop.

Basically I want to be able to go

```
var record = Context.Numbers.Where(x => x.Designation.StartsWith(number.SubString(0,5)).FirstOrDefault().
```

But being able to then change the length of the SubString() until the record is actually populated or the first 5 digits/characters have been exhausted.

Comment: "I was hoping this is doable without using loops. And just using Linq." - FYI, LINQ just internally uses loops as well.

Comment: @RexM Ah I see, I could rephrase to say writing in as little code as possible, not having to write a foreach/for loop.

Comment: Tricky, I can see two approaches. 1) search for all records that start with the first character, then search that list for records starting with the first two characters, and so on until you either get an empty list, or you get to the full 5 character substring. Or 2) search for all 5 characters first, then, if you list is empty, seach for 4, and so forth. Which is more efficient may depend on how likely you think it is for a miss versus a hit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pure Linq solution is

```
new []{5,4,3,2,1}.Select(len => Context.Numbers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Designation.StartsWith(number.SubString(0, len)))).FirstOrDefault(i => i != null);
```

The other base sequence initialization by the Enumerable.Range

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Reverse().Select(len => Context.Numbers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Designation.StartsWith(number.SubString(0, len)))).FirstOrDefault(i => i != null);
```

So it's a naive solution, but if you have a big dictionary you need the other solution to solve this issue.

Comment: Couldn't you replace the starting array with a call to `Enumerable.Range`?

Comment: I have replaced Range to array few seconds ago :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like below:

```
    Data GetMatch(List<Data> dataList, string number)
    {
        var match = new Data();
        int maxLength = 5;
        while (maxLength > 0)
        {
            if (dataList.Any(p => p.Designation.StartsWith(number.Substring(0, maxLength))))
            {
                match = dataList.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Designation.StartsWith(number.Substring(0, maxLength)));
                break;
            }
            maxLength--;
        }
        return match;
    }
```

Comment: The title of the question is "find *first* record"

Comment: Changed to First Record.